# Python Discord Bot Error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm currently programming my own discord bot. Now i'm trying, to do that, when the bot startet it sends a dm to me.

This is my code

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    owner = bot.get_user(520430044007628800)
    dm_channel = await owner.create_dm()
    await owner.send("Wir sind eingeloggt als User {}".format(bot.user.name),     tts=True)
```

but i'm always getting the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

and i have done some research but i found literally nothing i hope you guys can help me:) i appreciate it

Comment: Is the Error message about a `Bot object` or a `NonType` object? You said two different things in the title and the description.

Comment: sorry i misswrote that, its nonetype object

Comment: Do you have intents enabled and loaded within your bot definition?

Comment: No what's that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct intents needed in order to send DM messages, in this case you will need default and members intents enabled. [Here's the docs about discord.py intents.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html)

Also, the discord bot must also share a server with the account that you're trying to create DM with. That could be another reason why you're getting this error if it isn't because of intents.

Below is the code needed to make this work, assuming that you have intents enabled in your developer portal and the bot shares a server with the user ID sent into `get_user`.

```py
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

TOKEN = "your discord code here"

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    owner = bot.get_user(520430044007628800)
    await owner.send("Wir sind eingeloggt als User {}".format(bot.user.name),     tts=True)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i still get the error: Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:----\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:----", line 21, in on_ready
    await owner.send("Wir sind eingeloggt als User {}".format(bot.user.name), tts=True)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have default and members intents enabled.
After that try using fetch_user instead of get_user
Like this:

```
owner = bot.fetch_userI520430044007628800)
await owner.send("Wir sind eingeloggt als User {}".format(bot.user.name),     tts=True)
```

Comment: Also Im pretty sure that tts doesn't work in dm's, but I could be wrong about that